# ImageUrl check in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have below ItemTemplate in a gridview to get an Image from a folder. On behinde code I check if the Image exists, if the Image no existes it return an alternate picture but I cant get the code for if the Image do exists to use the string from the template.  Thanks for any help.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageUrl(Eval("PerfilId", "AdminFotoUser/UserPics/{0}.png") as string)%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

"behindecode"

```
protected string GetImageUrl(string input)
    {
        if (input.Equals("no"))
        {
            return "AdminFotoUser/UserPics/BGP1.png";
        }
        else
        {
            ???
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [FileInfo.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to test whether file exists.

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/AdminFotoUser/UserPics/BGP1.png");
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
if (fileInfo.Exists)
{
     // File exists in the folder           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass only the image Id it's cleaner since  (I guess) all your images are going to be located in the same folder,

```
protected string GetImageUrl(string input)
{
    var filepath = Server.MapPath(string.format("~/AdminFotoUser/UserPics/{0}.png",input));

    return File.Exists(filepath)?        
        string.format("AdminFotoUser/UserPics/{0}.png",input):        
        "AdminFotoUser/UserPics/default.png"; // otherwise return default pic

}
```

Comment: thanks, ...  but for some reason it retourns me the default.png always

Comment: try to search for the full file path then, I have updated my answer

Comment: remember the parameter in the binding should contain only "PerfilId"